# Reset and clear function in D3.js

Tags: d3.js, reset

I'm currently using the collapsible tree in D3.js http://www.robschmuecker.com/d3-js-drag-and-drop-zoomable-tree/. I added a search and clear function but I didn't manage to get it working properly.
The search function returns the count of results and shows in the tree in black the path to follow and green the results. But when I click on "clear" it only clears the results founds not the box or the tree.

```
function search () {
        var text = document.getElementById('searchField').value.toUpperCase();
        document.getElementById('searching').innerHTML = 'Searching: ' +text;

    //reset
        selected = [];
        scope = [];
        selection = '#a';

        baseSvg.selectAll(".nodeText").attr("fill", "black").style("fill-opacity", 0.3);
        baseSvg.selectAll("path").attr("r", 4.5).style("fill", function(d) {
            return d._children ? "green" : "#fff";
        });
        filtered = true;    

        root.children.forEach(searchChildren, text);
        baseSvg.selectAll(selected).attr("fill", "gold");
        baseSvg.selectAll(scope).style("fill-opacity", 1.0);

        document.getElementById('searching').innerHTML = 'Found: ' +selected.length;
    }

    function clearResult() {
        filtered = false;
        selected = [];
        scope = [];
        selection = '#a';
        root.children.forEach(clearNodes);
        baseSvg.selectAll(".nodeText").attr("fill", "black");
        baseSvg.selectAll(".nodeText").style("fill-opacity", 1);
        baseSvg.selectAll("path").attr("r", 4.5).style("fill", function(d) {
            return d._children ? "gold" : "#fff";
        });

  document.getElementById('searching').innerHTML = '';
    }

function clearNodes(d) {
        d.selected = 0;
        if (d.children)
            d.children.forEach(clearNodes);
        else if (d._children)
            d._children.forEach(clearNodes);
    }


    function searchChildren(d) {
        d.selected = 0;
        var patt = new RegExp("\\b"+this+"\\b", "i");
        //if (d.name.toUpperCase().indexOf(this) >= 0) {
        if (d.name.match(patt) != null) {
            selected.push('#' + d.marker);
            selection = selection + ', #' + d.marker;
            d.selected = 1;
            addToScope(d);
        }

        if (d.children)
            d.children.forEach(searchChildren, this);
        else if (d._children)
            d._children.forEach(searchChildren, this);

    }`
```

I thought that adding in the clearResults the collapse function (as below) would allow to go back to the original display.

`// Collapse all children of roots children before rendering.
root.children.forEach(function (child) {
    collapse(child);});`

As a beginner with D3.js I'm forgetting something here but I don't see what. Does someone has tips or advice? The full code is there http://codepen.io/mscfourn/full/zrwDc/
Thanks.

Comment: A fiddle, or some live demonstration, would be appreciated.

Comment: I added at the bottom of the question the link to the result on codepen. Here is the full code http://codepen.io/mscfourn/pen/zrwDc

Comment: Is the actual search working properly? From your question it seems like it's just the clear that's the issue, but I don't see the black path, and I get weird result highlighting that doesn't seem to properly match the elements.

Comment: You're right, the clear function is the issue. For me the search is working properly. When I search for guidelines for example and I open the international scale, the public law and the non_legally binding are written in black because this is where the results are, and if you open them the results written are in green. The rest is written in grey. The weird result may come from the green circles at the beginning. Only one or two should appear green when the results are found. I have to change this.

Answer (score 1):

You're not updating the nodes, so they don't change until the next time someone expands or collapses one. You can add the line

```
update(root);
```

at the end of your clear and search methods to have the effect be immediately visible.